# Calendar Header (Text, Buttons) not showing in jquerymobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

I have upgraded my application to the latest fullcalender release 2.4.0.
Since then I've detected that also standard behaviour like drag'n drop is not working and also the header is not rendered/shown.
The only header attribute that seems to work is the title, showing the current month. The layout is also different from the layout in the examples.

Are there any known conflicts, bugs of fullcalendar and jquerymobile?

Environment: 
-jquerymobile 1.4.5 
- FullCalendar 2.4.0
- Fullcalendar initialization is done in the "pageshow" event of jquerymobile.

I've tested it with older releases of Fullcalender. Nothing worked until the release 1.6.7 which seems to working.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/fullcalendar.print.css" rel='stylesheet' media='print'>
```

from my header and it worked.